# галерея не хочет правильно работать, отменяется метод preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

пытаюсь сделать простую галерею в одну страницу, но при подмене после подмены значения атрибутов почему-то происходит загрузка картинки в новом окне.
вот код. Суть в том, чтоб в #big в src подставлялось значение href картинки и загружалось потом в том же окне, но все хорошо только до тех пор, пока не добавляется

```
 $('#big img').load(function () {
                    $(this).fadeIn(2000);
                });
```

после чего при клике просто загружается новая страница с картинкой, вместо того, чтоб загрузить ее на том же месте вместо start.jpg

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title>Email input page</title>
            <style>
#gallery {
    padding: 20px;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    width: 483px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 380px;
}
#big {
    background-image: url("../images/gal/loader.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 483px;
    height: 302px;
    border:1px dotted #cccccc;
}
#small {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 33px;
}
#small a img{
    border:none;
}
</style>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script> $(document).ready(function($) {


        $('#small a').click(function (eventObj) {
            $('#big img').hide().attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
            $('#big img').load(function () {
                $(this).fadeIn(2000);
            });

            eventObj.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div id="gallery">
            <div id="big"><img src="images/gal/start.jpg" alt="Старт" /></div>
            <div id="small">
                <a href="images/gal/1.jpg"><img src="images/gal/1_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 1" /></a>
                <a href="images/gal/2.jpg"><img src="images/gal/2_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 2" /></a>
                <a href="images/gal/3.jpg"><img src="images/gal/3_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 3" /></a>
                <a href="images/gal/4.jpg"><img src="images/gal/4_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 4" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/load/ - первый параметр - адрес, а не функция.

Ваш вызов `$('#big img').load` приводит к ошибке, после которой выполнение не доходит до `eventObj.preventDefault`, и анкер грузит то, что указано в его `href`.

Переставьте `eventObj.preventDefault();` в начало обработчика, тогда Вы сможете увидеть сообщение об ошибке в консоли браузера.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. В конечном итоге я убрал .load(function(){}) и просто прописал $('#big img').fadeIn(2000); и все заработало как надо.